# Discord Python : how to set custom parameters to allow use of a function or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hey I got a discord bot and I want to set "permissions" for use some commands, like commands for staff, commands avaible with given roles, or even with a minimal level.

So I try to put each of my commands in class :

````py
class class_test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.minimal_level = 0
        self.minimal_role_name = "valid_member"
        self.reset_time = 5
        self.pass_role = 0
        self.last_execution = 0
        self.executions = 0
        self.ban_members = []
        self.ban_role_name = ["mute", "warn 1", "warn 2"]


    @bot.command()
    async def __call__(self, ctx, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if self.minimal_role in ctx.author.roles :

                await ctx.send("do somthing")
            else:
                await ctx.send("This role no able to do this command !")

        except Exception as exception:
            await ctx.send(f"an error as occurs : ```{exception}```")
````

But It's not work at all. Then I found the cogs but If I use them for each commands, I could'nt separate by sections like staff_commands, game_economy, game_fight, game_utils, settings, etc, ...

I thought also to do, for each commands, an variable in my Cog class with `self.function_foo_perm = {minimal_level : 0, minimal_rol......}` but is it really a good solution ?

Finally, I thought to make a special class for stroing the permission.

But what the best way ? Or is it something better ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated: You are misusing classes. What you are doing "works" but it is incredibly hacky.

---

The discord.py library has many checks decorators that covers a lot of what you need:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#checks

In case of the roles you do:

```
@commands.has_role("rolename"/roleid)
@commands.has_any_role("rolename"/roleid,"rolename"/roleid,"rolename"/roleid ...)
@bot.command()
async def ...
```

---

Custom checks can be implemented like following:

```
def check_if_it_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == 85309593344815104

@bot.command()
@commands.check(check_if_it_is_me)
async def only_for_me(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I know you!')
```

Comment: but how to check reset time, ban member, etc ?

Comment: I edited my answer and included an example on how to write a custom check.